# How to pass List of Data object as an interface using Java in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to pass an object as an interface, 
when i use just one object, it's not a problem,

like this It doesn't error out >

```
@SerializedName("cost")
private myCostImpl visitCost;
```

then this is not erroring out when i pass the interface itself (although i called the model before that implements this interface)>

```
@Override
public myCostInterface getVisitCost() { return visitCost; }
```

but when i try to do it to a list like >

```
@SerializedName("enterprises")
private List<EnterpriseImpl> enterprises;
```

it errors out on the >

```
@Override
public List<Enterprise> getEnterprises() {
   return enterprises;
}
```

(also EnterpriseImpl is implementing Enterprise)

both of the Models Implement the Interfaces the same way.
the only difference is that one is a list.

how can i fix this ? and still pass the interface on a List Object ?

Answer (score 0):

`EnterpriseImpl` is `Enterprise`, but `Enterprise` is not necessary an `EnterpriseImp`.

You have to find another approach.

Comment: well why does it work with , myCostImpl then ? it's exactly the same... only difference between them is that one is a list and the other is not. and it doesn't error out myCostImpl.